# What is the theoretical maximum efficiency of converting electricity to EM radiation? Is there such a thing?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity

It turns out LEDs can have an [efficiency of more than 100%](https://phys.org/news/2012-03-efficiency.html), i.e. they output more light energy than electrical energy goes in. The 'missing' energy is taken from their thermal energy so the LED cools down slightly in this configuration. So in a way the LED in this particular setup shows some heat-pump-like behavior.

Taking such heat-pump-like shenanigans into account, is there any theoretical limit with which electricity can be converted into light (or other types of electromagnetic radiation)? If so what is it?

Edit: Of course any object with a temperature above absolute zero emits thermal radiation. So I will accept the efficiency of any conversion of electricity into radiation above this thermal background as an answer.

Comment: Thermal energy alone can be used to produce light, without any electrical energy input. In fact it's happening all around you all the time (but most of the light is in the infrared bands for the stuff around you).

Comment: Any time you see claims of "efficiencies above 100%", be very suspicious. It's true that an LED at room temperature will emit blackbody radiation even in the absence of any electrical power inputs, but that's not the same as efficiencies greater than 100%.  Either the original research is flawed, or (more likely) the translation of its results into the popular press article you cited misinterpreted what the researchers actually said.

Comment: @ThePhoton true, I edited the answer to take that into account. The infrared light measured from the LED in the linked article is not thermal background.

Comment: @DavidRose While I agree in general, I think this particular article is legit. I had a look at the abstract of the original published article, and also the results are in line with previous theoretical predictions. Heat pumps in general have an efficiency above 100% because they can extract heat from the ambient temperature.